# Convertir Archivos Binarios a Texto

Tags: c#

hola estoy en búsqueda de ayuda con un pequeño problema que tengo

mi duda es como puedo convertir el texto que contiene un fichero.txt a binario y viceversa

tengo entendido que utilizado la Clase BinaryWriter puedo convertir texto en binario en si con lo que tengo mas problema y me confunde es cuando quiero regresar los números binarios a texto que contiene un archivo.txt

por ejemplo en el archivo.txt ingreso "hola mundo"
cuando lo convierto a binario quedaria `[][]|`

entonces mi duda es como hago para que esos números binarios regresen a ser texto ?

algun consejo ?

Comment: Publica lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Jeff,

Puedes optar por usar el `BinaryWriter`, o puedes usar estos métodos que no usan ninguna libreria externa como los siguientes:

Función para pasar texto a binario:

```
public static string StringToBinary(string texto)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in texto.ToCharArray())
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Función para pasar binarios a texto:

```
public static string BinaryToString(string texto)
{
    List<Byte> byteList = new List<Byte>();

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.Length; i += 8)
    {
        byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(texto.Substring(i, 8), 2));
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteList.ToArray());
}
```